# How to add items to a dictionary from a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to check an xml file for nodes `disp-formula` which has a attribute "**id**" and the attribute contains values like `deqnX-Y` where both `X` and `Y` are integers and if match found then add them in the below manner in a dictionary

```
Key                             Value
"rid="deqnX""               "rid="deqnX-Y""
"rid="deqnX+1""             "rid="deqnX-Y""
...  ...
"rid="deqnY""               "rid="deqnX-Y""

incrementing value of X by 1 till it reaches Y
```

I've tried the below code but got stuck middle way and I can't figure out what to do.

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Practice\test.xml",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
            var x =from y in doc.Descendants("disp-formula")
                   where y.Attribute("id").Value.Contains(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)")
                   select y.Attribute("id");
            foreach (var item in x)
            {

                dict.Add(item);
            }
```

Here is a sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article article-type="research">
<front>
<journal-meta>
<issn pub-type="paper">0327-286X</issn>
<publisher>
<publisher-name>IEEE</publisher-name>
</publisher>
</journal-meta>
<article-meta>
<article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1245/11.202136</article-id>
<title-group>
<article-title>Dragon Ball Super popularity in USA</article-title>
</title-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="S1">
<label>1.</label>
<p>....
<disp-formula id="deqn1">
...
</disp-formula>
</p>
</sec>
<sec id="S2">
<label>2.</label>
<p>...
<disp-formula id="deqn2-6">
...
</disp-formula></p>
<p>...
<disp-formula id="deqn7">
...
</disp-formula>
</p>
<p><disp-formula id="deqn8-10">
...
</disp-formula></p>
</sec>
</body>
</article>
```

This should be the dictionary items after running the program

```
Key                             Value
"rid="deqn2""               "rid=""deqn2-6""
"rid="deqn3""               "rid=""deqn2-6""
"rid="deqn4""               "rid=""deqn2-6""
"rid="deqn5""               "rid=""deqn2-6""
"rid="deqn6""               "rid=""deqn2-6""
"rid="deqn8""               "rid=""deqn8-10""
"rid="deqn9""               "rid=""deqn8-10""
"rid="deqn10""              "rid=""deqn8-10""
```

Comment: You can't add `item` to `dic` because it is not correspond argument for `Add`

Comment: You need to explain more about the problem domain. I don't understand what the algorithim is supposed to be. In anycase, you could use something like this to convert to a dictionary but as I say you need to explain more what to output is supposed to be. `var dict = x.ToDictionary(o => new {o.Name, o.Value});`

Comment: the string.Contains method dosen accept regex, but simple string.

Comment: can you show a complete entry of disp-formula? or explain where the Y value?

Comment: @pmcilreavy I want to find the xml file for nodes `disp-formula` with id having the structure deqnX-Y, then simply put that value **deqnX-Y** as **value** in the dictionary and the respective **keys** should be the **deqnX** to **deqnY** where X = X+1,

Comment: @lomed In a node `<disp-formula id="deqn4-6">`, `X` is the value 4 and `Y` is the value 6 and I need to get all value from the range 4-6 i.e. 4,5 and 6 and then put them in the **key** position of the dictionary but adding sum strings to it so the keys look like `rid="deqn4", rid="deqn5", rid="deqn6"`, and each of their **value** counterparts should be `rid="deqn4-6"` and this should be the case for all matches.

Comment: @Bumba how `"rid="deqn5""  -  "rid=""deqn2-6""` its valid?

Comment: @Bumba ok, I understood. It was not easy... See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var regex = new Regex(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)");

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Practice\test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var x = from y in doc.Descendants("disp-formula")
        let m = regex.Match(y.Attribute("id").Value)
        where m.Success
        select m;


foreach (var item in x)
{
    var from = int.Parse(item.Groups[1].Value);
    var to = int.Parse(item.Groups[2].Value);
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)\\< should be <=
        dict.Add("deqn" + i, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: your code is missing the Y part in the dictionary. i.e. `deqn6` and `deqn10` are missing in output.

Answer (score 5):

This problem consists of:

1. Find the elements that match the regex
2. Get X and Y from the matched string
3. Increment X until Y and store them in Dictionary

---

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Practice\test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var regex = new Regex(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)");

// Get matches by the regex
var matches = from dispFormula in xdoc.Descendants("disp-formula")
                select regex.Match(dispFormula.Attribute("id").Value);
// We want only successes
matches = matches.Where(match => match.Success);

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    // If input string is "deqn2-6", 
    //   match.Groups[0].Value = "deqn2-6", 
    //   match.Groups[1].Value = "2", 
    //   match.Groups[2].Value = "6", so
    int x = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    int y = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

    // Now we have to increment x until y
    for (int i = 0; x + i <= y; i++)
    {
        dict.Add($"deqn{x + i}", $"deqn{x}-{y}");
    }
}

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key={entry.Key}, Value={entry.Value}");
}
```

This outputs

```
Key=deqn2, Value=deqn2-6
Key=deqn3, Value=deqn2-6
Key=deqn4, Value=deqn2-6
Key=deqn5, Value=deqn2-6
Key=deqn6, Value=deqn2-6
Key=deqn8, Value=deqn8-10
Key=deqn9, Value=deqn8-10
Key=deqn10, Value=deqn8-10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike..:)

Comment: @Bumba My pleasure, glad to be of ur help :)

Comment: BTW, If I do it on an array of xml files one by one should I put the `dict.Clear()` command after the last `foreach` loop, as for every file the dictionary items will be different and some files may not even have the node `disp-formula` or may not have the id attribute with a numeric ranges.

Comment: @Bumba That really depends on the use case. If you want a dictionary for each xml file, I think you should put the code in a new method that takes an xml file and returns a dictionary, and call it on each xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code but it doesn't work with your provided Xml

so it is better to use `Regex` to find you sequence, as the below code:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Practice\test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)");
 var x = from y in doc.Descendants("disp-formula").ToList()
                where reg.IsMatch(y.Attribute("id").Value)
                select y.Attribute("id");
```

and as I tell you in comment you cant add `item` to `dic`, for counter you can also use `Regex` to get first number and then increase it as:

```
int counter = 0;
 foreach (var item in x)
 {
   var str = item.Value.Split('-')[0];
   if (counter == 0)
      counter = Convert.ToInt16(new Regex(@"\d+$").Match(str).Value) - 1;
   dict.Add("deqn" + (counter++).ToString(), item.Value);
 }
```

the real working code would be:

```
int counter = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Practice\test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
Regex reg = new Regex(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)");
(from y in doc.Descendants("disp-formula").ToList()
         where reg.IsMatch(y.Attribute("id").Value)
         select y.Attribute("id")).ToList().ForEach(item=>
          {

            if (counter == 0)
                 counter = Convert.ToInt16(new Regex(@"\d+$").Match(item.Value.Split('-')[0]).Value) - 1;
                 dict.Add("deqn" + (++counter).ToString(), item.Value);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.`

Comment: Yes the sample one is just an example because `item.Name` would be `id` and it is duplicated, you try the last snipped code.

Comment: your code gives keys as `"deqn1", "deqn2"` where it should be `"deqn2", "deqn3", "deqn4", "deqn5", "deqn6", "deqn8", "deqn9", "deqn10"` . Maybe you misunderstood the requirements. Anyways thank you for sharing your method..:)

Comment: No it is really do what you want, you tested it before my last edit , that was beacause of `++` priority, you just test it, my code is note complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158791/discussion-between-aria-and-bumba).

Answer (score 1):

This is the final program that I wanted to build

```
string[] path=Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text,"xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .SelectMany(x=>Directory.GetFiles(x,"*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray();
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var regex = new Regex(@"deqn(\d+)-(\d+)");
            foreach (var file in path) {
                dict.Clear();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                var x = from y in doc.Descendants("disp-formula")
                    let m = regex.Match(y.Attribute("id").Value)
                    where m.Success
                    select m;
                foreach (var item in x)
                {
                    var from = int.Parse(item.Groups[1].Value);
                    var to = int.Parse(item.Groups[2].Value);
                    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
                        dict.Add("rid=\"deqn" + i+"\"", "rid=\""+item.Value+"\"");

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> element in dict) {
                        string text=File.ReadAllText(file);
                        text=text.Replace(element.Key,element.Value);
                        File.WriteAllText(file, text);
                    }

                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Thanks to both @lomed and @Mike Mat for helping me out on this one ...:)